# How do I stop the item from the array to repeat after it has been shown

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I stop the item from the Array being repeated more than once straight after each other when refreshed.

I have tried splice, but it isn't working, maybe I am doing it wrong?

```html
<script>
      var r_text = new Array();
      
      //Change the local links to server links
      r_text[0] = '<a href="http://bitbulb.io/posts/9">Calculator</a>';
      r_text[1] = '<a href="http://bitbulb.io/posts/8">Todo List</a>';
      r_text[2] = '<a href="http://bitbulb.io/posts/10">Number Sorting Application</a>';
      r_text[3] = '<a href="http://bitbulb.io/posts/11">Text Encryption / Decryption Application</a>';
      r_text[4] = '<a href="http://bitbulb.io/posts/12">Alarm Clock</a>';

      var i = Math.floor(r_text.length * Math.random());
       document.write(r_text[i]);
        
    </script>
```

Comment: You can use `localStorage` to save the last `i` value. You can then check if current `i` matches old `i`, if true then run the script again.

Comment: Thank you, I actually didn't think of that. I will be sure to try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One the way to solve this problem is using localStorage and save all showed links. After page refresh you can get values from localStorage by key and filter links. So you will get only unshowed links

```
var key = 'ids';
var arr = [
    '<a href="http://bitbulb.io/posts/9">Calculator</a>',
  '<a href="http://bitbulb.io/posts/8">Todo List</a>',
  '<a href="http://bitbulb.io/posts/10">Number Sorting Application</a>',
  '<a href="http://bitbulb.io/posts/11">Text Encryption / Decryption Application</a>',
  '<a href="http://bitbulb.io/posts/12">Alarm Clock</a>'
];

start(arr, key);

function start(arr, key){
  var showedLinks = getFromStorage(key);
  var len = arr.length;

  if (showedLinks.length == len){
    saveToStorage([], key);
    showedLinks = [];
  }

  var unshowedLinks = arr.filter( link => showedLinks.indexOf(link) === -1);
  var randomIndex = getRandom(unshowedLinks.length);
  var randomLink = unshowedLinks[randomIndex];

  var elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.innerHTML = randomLink;
  document.body.appendChild(elem);

  showedLinks.push(randomLink);
  saveToStorage(showedLinks, key);  
}

function getRandom(len){
    return Math.floor(len * Math.random());
}

function saveToStorage(data, key){
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
}

function getFromStorage(key){
  var data = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
  return data? JSON.parse(data): [];
}
```